# Редерект в php header

Tags: php

В форме регистрации нужно сделать редерект на дом страницу, или я косой или функция header это танец с бубном, пробывал из отдельного файла подключать, проблема в том что header должен будть выше requery соответсвенно, возникает закономерный вопрос, а как он должен работать с пока-что несуществуещими переменами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так танцы с бубном, но я нашел способ - просто введите `exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /туда-куда надо.php'>");`

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['text']) ) {
тут обработка данных с формы
...
header('Location: /');}
```

Если я правильно вас понял, то так должно работать.

```
 <?php 
  if( isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['text']) ) {
    тут обработка данных с формы
    ...
    header('Location: /');}
 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>!DOCTYPE</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
     ...
   </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: я про то, что header для меня это очень проблемно, у меня всегда ошибка Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: вот этот код я смогу вставить в любую строку ?

Comment: Ошибка Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by возникает потому что вы написание header после отправки html. Попробуйте в самый вверх вставить.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, что даже в самом начале Тоесть строка до тега doctype не работает

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ и добавил html. У вас примерно так же щас?

Comment: Да,  и оно не работает, если я ставлю поч совсем вверх,  около запуска ссеси, то просто нечего не происходит